# OpenStack Instance not using up full space

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, openstack, nova-network

I have created new instance with Centos 6.4 with 20 GB Disk Space but when i logging to the VPS and Execute df -h the space shown as the following

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1             984M  706M  229M  76% /
none                 1012M     0 1012M   0% /dev/shm
```

and the output of fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/vda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
4 heads, 32 sectors/track, 327680 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 128 * 512 = 65536 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a5c87

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/vda1              17       16401     1048640   83  Linux
```

i need the vda1 taking all the space of vda how i can do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to resize partition, then grow filesystem:

1. Take backup
2. fdisk /dev/vda -> d -> 1 -> n -> p -> 1 -> 17 -> [enter]
3. -> p

   ensure that partition is marked with asterisk (*) to be bootable, if not:

   a -> 1

   when done -> w
4. resize2fs /dev/vda1

   (online process, wait!)
5. reboot

Note: You are missing swap partition, you can use +xxxxM instead if [enter] to leave some space for swap partition.

Comment: I need this automatically when i create the instance , the default image for openstack is fedora 19 not have this problem this problem with any images like centos , windows and other , when i trying to install centos from ISO file there are not any disk appears

Comment: this is how it is. You need to configure parameters during installation or you need other image.